# Modifying object at a particular index overwrites the same property for other indexes too

Tags: javascript

I have an object array armies having 4 entries. When i try to modify availableVehicle property for a particular index, availableVehicle property for all indexes gets updated

```js
let armies = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  armies.push({
    selectedPlanet: {
      name: "",
      distance: 0,
    },
    selectedVehicle: {
      name: "",
      max_distance: 0,
      speed: 0,
      total_no: 0,
    },
    availablePlanets: [],
    availableVehicles: [],
  });
}
let temp1 = [
  { name: "Space pod", total_no: 2, max_distance: 200, speed: 2 },
  { name: "Space rocket", total_no: 1, max_distance: 300, speed: 4 },
  { name: "Space shuttle", total_no: 1, max_distance: 400, speed: 5 },
  { name: "Space ship", total_no: 2, max_distance: 600, speed: 4 },
];

armies.map((army) => {
  army.availableVehicles = Object.assign(temp1);
  return army;
});

armies[0].availableVehicles[2].total_no -= 1; //total no gets updated for all the indexes.

armies.forEach((army) => console.log(army.availableVehicles[2].total_no));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `temp1` is of reference type (when you assign it to the army, you assign the same array to all of the army objects) and to prevent this you'll need to deep clone this array when assigning to an army. One way of doing deep clone is by using an npm package like this one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone-deep

If you want to read more about reference type in javascript:
https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0?gi=bdc927bbae59

Examples for how you can create a copy of `temp1`:

```
let temp1 = [
  { name: "Space pod", total_no: 2, max_distance: 200, speed: 2 },
  { name: "Space rocket", total_no: 1, max_distance: 300, speed: 4 },
  { name: "Space shuttle", total_no: 1, max_distance: 400, speed: 5 },
  { name: "Space ship", total_no: 2, max_distance: 600, speed: 4 },
];

let temp1_copy1 = temp1.map(v => ({...v})); //this will work as long as there are no more nested objects/arrays inside

const cloneDeep = require('clone-deep');
let temp1_copy2 = cloneDeep(temp1); 

let temp1_copy3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp1)); //the easiest and shortest way but can cause lost of data when data is more complex (like functions, date, symbols and undefined)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new copy of `temp1`

```js
let armies = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  armies.push({
    selectedPlanet: {
      name: "",
      distance: 0,
    },
    selectedVehicle: {
      name: "",
      max_distance: 0,
      speed: 0,
      total_no: 0,
    },
    availablePlanets: [],
    availableVehicles: [],
  });
}
let temp1 = [{
    name: "Space pod",
    total_no: 2,
    max_distance: 200,
    speed: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Space rocket",
    total_no: 1,
    max_distance: 300,
    speed: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Space shuttle",
    total_no: 1,
    max_distance: 400,
    speed: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Space ship",
    total_no: 2,
    max_distance: 600,
    speed: 4
  },
];

armies.map((army) => {
  army.availableVehicles = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp1)); // changed here
  return army;
});
armies[0].availableVehicles[2].total_no -= 1;
armies.forEach((army) => console.log(army.availableVehicles[2].total_no));
```